# Does snowflake sql api support concurrent users?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please suggest on below

As per [this link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/guide.html#limitations-of-the-sql-api)

> The service does not currently support fetching results concurrently (i.e. in parallel with multiple threads). Requests are supported only from a single thread

Does it mean only one user can call an API at a time? Please suggest if we can use those APIs for concurrent users?

If not then what is the future plan to get the concurrent users support from Snowflake side?

Comment: No, it just means what when an individual user executes a SQL query they cannot fetch the results with a multi threaded process. Multiple users can still run queries concurrently. Snowflake would be pretty useless if multiple users couldn't use it at the same time!!

Comment: Thanks Simon for reply, please suggest any snowflake link to verify the same ,that will help me to support this point from snowflake reference documentation .Thanks. – Neeraj

Comment: The docs you linked to say it...

Answer (score 1):

It means the process itself cannot be multi-threaded. There is no limit, apart from performance limitations, on the number of concurrent calls

Comment: Thanks Nick for reply, please suggest any snowflake link to verify the same ,that will help me to support this point from snowflake reference documentation .Thanks.

Comment: See Simon D’s comment